# Add theme support to existing android application

Tags: android, themes

Yes, this is probably another question about Android styles/themes, etc. but I wasn't able to find a solution that fits my case, which is:

I have an existing application with (probably nothing uncommon):

- `colors.xml` - containing a lot of colour codes
- `themes.xml` - containing a styles waterfall (meaning a lot of styles have a parent, that have parents, that also have parents... e.g. BaseTheme, ModalBaseTheme has BaseTheme as parent, SpecialModalBaseTheme has ModalBaseThem as parent)
- some images inside drawables folder

When I launch my application, I have a screen where I can select what I've called "Skin" (imagine we have a Blue and a Red Skin), which basically have different colours (set in themes, so different themes) and different images.

After selecting the Skin on this screen, the application re-starts with that info stored. So, my first intuition was to be able to select a different `resources` folder based on the selected Skin (notice that every time I change the Skin, the application restarts, so it shouldn't be a problem right?). Is this possible?

Also tried to follow a lot of tutorials using `setTheme` but the project structure does not make it easy to find every `onCreate` or to know where to set each theme. Should I invest in this approach?

Thanks

Comment: As for `setTheme`: You only need to set it for each activity, and they are not hard to find as they are declared in manifest. Cleanest approach is writing custom base activity that handles theme switching in its `onCreate` and have all Your other activities extend it.

Comment: Hi @Pawel. We have backgrounds declared in layouts, we have fragments... I find this so messy! I cannot use the Base Activity approach because each activity uses a different theme... It is not a theme for the whole application, but for each little part (e.g. a modal has a theme, the side menu has a theme...). Is this the correct use for themes?

Comment: If every component can get styled independent of host activity it does start looking quite messy. Hard to give insight without seeing project structure, but You should still try to set theme or use [`ContextThemeWrapper`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper) to inflate themed views in each component.